# How to use own methods with non-static webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I heard is bad practice to set the WebDriver instance and methods as static.
I removed it from my code, but I have the problem now:
I got error in Class: "LoginPage.java" in method: "setLoginAndPassword()":

> The method setValueInField(By, String) is undefined for the type
>   LoginPage

and:

> The method clickIn(By) is undefined for the type LoginPage

How to resolve it? Maybe inheritance ? But Java doesn't support multiple inheritance ( class LoginPage.java would have to extends ClickFunctions and InputFunctions

My code:
package: utils, class: Initialize.java:

```
public class Initialize {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "c:\\tests\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

package: test, class: MainTests.java

```
  public class MainTests extends Initialize{
        @Test
        public void test(){
            LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
            loginPage.getLoginPage();
            HomePage homePage = loginPage.setLoginAndPassword();
        }
    }
```

package: pageobjects, class: LoginPage.java:

```
public class LoginPage{
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    private WebDriver driver;
    private By login = By.cssSelector("#Login");
    private By password = By.cssSelector("#Password");
    private By submit = By.cssSelector("#submit");

    public LoginPage getLoginPage(){
        driver.get("https://verytest.pl");
        return this;
    }

    public HomePage setLoginAndPassword(){
        setValueInField(login,"anylogin");
        setValueInField(password,"anypass");
        clickIn(submit);
        return new HomePage(driver);
    }

}
```

package: functions, class: ClickFunctions.java:

```
public class ClickFunctions extends Initialize{
    public void clickIn(By locator){
        new WebDriverWait(driver,120).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
        driver.findElement(locator).click();
    }
}
```

package: functions, class: InputFunctions.java:

```
public class InputFuntions extends Initialize{
    public void setValueInField(By locator, String fieldValue){
        new WebDriverWait(driver,120).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(fieldValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor InputFunctions or ClickFunctions as a utility class (no need to extends Initialize then).

Example

```
public class InputFuntions {
    public static void setValueInField(WebDriver driver, By locator, String fieldValue){
        new WebDriverWait(driver,120).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(fieldValue);
    }
}
```

You can then static import it and use it

```
import static my.package.InputFuntions.*

   public class LoginPage{
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    private WebDriver driver;
    private By login = By.cssSelector("#Login");
    private By password = By.cssSelector("#Password");
    private By submit = By.cssSelector("#submit");

    public LoginPage getLoginPage(){
        driver.get("https://verytest.pl");
        return this;
    }

    public HomePage setLoginAndPassword(){
        setValueInField(driver, login,"anylogin");
        setValueInField(driver, password,"anypass");
        clickIn(driver,submit);
        return new HomePage(driver);
    }

}
```

If you find it tedious to add driver every time, you can create a base class for your page and define every utility inside.

Example

```
 public class Page {

 protected Webdriver driver;
 public void setValueInField(By locator, String fieldValue){
        new WebDriverWait(driver,120).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(fieldValue);
    }
// add other method here
}
```

Example usage

```
public class LoginPage extends Page{
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    private WebDriver driver;
    private By login = By.cssSelector("#Login");
    private By password = By.cssSelector("#Password");
    private By submit = By.cssSelector("#submit");

    public LoginPage getLoginPage(){
        driver.get("https://verytest.pl");
        return this;
    }

    public HomePage setLoginAndPassword(){
        setValueInField(login,"anylogin");
        setValueInField(password,"anypass");
        clickIn(submit);
        return new HomePage(driver);
    }

}
```

And finally, you can also use java 8 default method. By defining each utility class as an interface with default methods (like clickIn) and a getDriver() that can be implemented by page using those utilities. (It is a kind of multiple inheritance).

Comment: With: java 8 default method approach will be problem with driver in interfaces: